# RxJs Observable make requests in parallel until it fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs, observer-pattern

I want to reach an API that returns data in pages of 50 items, but I dont know how many items (and therefore pages) there are.

My idea is to send 20 requests in parallel, each one will request the ith page and then the ith+20 page, and so on, until a page returns blank, in which case I end.

With this approach I would do at most 20 unnecessary requests.

The thing is, I don't know how to structure this loop using observables.

I imagined something like this:

```
return Observable.from(_.range(0, 20))
  .map((pageNo) => fetchPage(pageNo))
  .while((page) => isValid(page));
```

but this `while` method or similars dont exist/work

I found this similar question but he uses `interval`, which seems inefficient [RxJs Observable interval until reached desired value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38607121/1250593)

From my understanding, I can't use `takeWhile`because it validates the condition already met, and not a response of the request still to be made.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
return Observable.from(_.range(0, 20)).pipe(
    mergeMap(pageNo => ajax.getJSON(`/api/fetchPage/${pageNo}`).pipe(
        mergeMap(result => 
            of(addPersonFulfilled(result), secondFunc(foo)),
            retryWhen(error => tap(console.log('error on page', error)))
        )           
    ))
)
```

Comment: can you explain what this does?

Answer (score 1):

You can create 20 requests and wait for all of them to complete with `forkJoin` and then use `takeWhile` to complete the chain when the array of results is empty:

```
const fetchPage = page => {
  ...
  return forkJoin(...);
};

range(0, 20).pipe(
  concatMap(page => fetchPage(page)),
  takeWhile(arr => arr.length > 0),
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

Complete demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zw1sr2?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Nice, thank you. I wasn't familiar with this pipe function.

Comment: after further examination of your answer, I think you misunderstood my question. Your code fires 20 fetchPage, and each fetches (currently logs) 20 times. The stopping clause should be on the second loop, not the first.

Comment: You mean inside fetchPage()?

Comment: the 20 in the range is correct, the 20 inside the for loop needs to be something that takes in consideration the response from the request, i.e. if there is data returning in that request. This is where the stopping condition should be (from my way of thinking how to solve the problem, unless you are suggesting something different)